# How to display bool values in a view and save the value to DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table that has bit values (true/false)

Table Definition:

```
CharacterID int 
isActive    bit 
UserId  uniqueidentifier
```

I have 2 problems:

1. How to display the existing selected option in the edit view in a Dropdown
2. I need to save the value (yes/No) as true and false in the database.

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("", new SelectListItem[] { new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value = "true", Selected = Model.IsActive }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "No", Value = "false", Selected = !Model.IsActive }})
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that model.IsActive is declared as `bool`:

Wouldn't using a CheckBox be a bit more intuitive to the user and require less clicks?
In that case you could just use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive)
```

If you really want dropdowns, then this SO might provide a working implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4036922/1373170

Applied to your context, I believe it would be:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IsActive, new SelectList(new SelectListItem[] { new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value = "True" }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "No", Value = "False"}}, model.IsActive.ToString())
```

Now, for saving it to the database I'd have to know if you are using EF, L2S, etc.
But I imagine you already have an action in your controller set up for saving. In that case it is probably already receiving an instance of your model as parameter. Using DropDownListFor instead of DropDownList, your model should be bound automatically by MVC's default `ModelBinder`, and you should be able to map that to your database entity and store it.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple things you need to setup for drop-down and viewmodel property to make this work.

1) Your view model:

```
public class MyModel
    {
        public MyModel()
        {            
            BoolSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>(); 
        }

        public int CharacterID { get; set; }
        public bool isActive   { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId  { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> BoolSelectList { get; set; }
    }
```

2) In controller you need to assign value to bool Value and List

```
public MyModel viewmodel = new MyModel();
// Set other properties of viewmodel
// ....
// Set Drop-down List values
 viewModel.BoolSelectList = new SelectList(new SelectListItem[] { new SelectListItem()                   { Text = "Yes", Value = "True" }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "No", Value = "False"}};
```

3) In your view :

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.isActive, "Is Active ")
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.isActive, Model.BoolSelectList, model.IsActive.ToString())
```

On your Post action, the value of IsActive should be True/False depending on your selection.